# Tesnor Flow unsupported opperand

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, operand

I am going to use tensor flow package to run models/rnn/ptb/
ptb_worl_lm.py.
However, I have got this error in seq2Seq.py,

> line 653, in sequence_loss_by_example
>
> log_perps /= total_size
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /=: 'Tensor' and 'Tensor'

I am using Ubuntu, and python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running with the released version of tensorflow and using a post-release model, by chance?  This sounds a lot like [Github issue 293](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/293).  My suggestion would be to either:  (a)  Update your install;  (b)  Try removing the `from __future__ import division` from the top of the file; or (c) changing the line to invoke the underlying `log_perps = tf.div(log_perps, total_size)` function directly.

(b) or (c) is the fastest fix, but in the long run, I'd go with (a).